# Feature significance after linear fit on pca

Tags: python, linear-regression, pca

I have 14 independent variable which are highly corelated.
I want to do multiple linear regression and want to know feature significance.

I used PCA and selected 6 features which explained 98% variation where variation explained by them are [0.62,0.79,0.89,0.95,0.97,0.98].

I fitted the linear model on these principal components with coefficient derived by linear regression are [ 115,  104, -186,  134,   127,  195].

My confusion is how to find significance of original variable while predicting target variable?

Shall I check original feature significance in PC6 as it has highest weightage given by linear model or shall I check in PC1 as it has highest explained variation by PCA?